# How to strip out a -D for just one file in a gnu makefile?

Tags: makefile, overriding, rules, gnu-make

I have '-Wredundant-decls' in my CXXFLAGS but for one file, I want it removed.

In my GNU makefile, how can I structure a rule to remove just that part of the CXXFLAGS.

I know how to add only for that file, I would do something like this:

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS += -Wredundant-decls
```

So, ideally I'd do something like this (which doesn't work) to remove it:

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS -= -Wredundant-decls
```

However, maybe with some $ magic, I can construct some kind of sed or perl script to strip out the -Wredundant-decls and set CXXFLAGS to the stripped value:

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS = $(shell strip magic here for $CXXFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the shell:

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS := $(subst -Wredundant-decls,,$(CXXFLAGS))
```

or

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS := $(filter-out -Wredundant-decls,$(CXXFLAGS))
```

Comment: Gnu make rejects this syntax.

    /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: The second one you added is rejected too.  They are probably close, but there is some issue with the syntax.  Seems the $CXXFLAGS is not expanding.

Comment: Just remove the last `)` of the line, it's a typo.

Comment: No, the typo was a missing (. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out for myself:

```
$O/just_one_file.o: CXXFLAGS := $(shell echo ${CXXFLAGS} | sed s/-Wredundant-decls//g)
```