# How can I add -Wno-unused-private-field to just one file?

Tags: c++, gnu-make

I have an unused private variable occurring in just one C++ source file, I don't want to fix it as it will be used in the future and I want to know if any other files end up with this error, so I'd like to add `-Wno-unused-private-field` to just one source file's rules.  How can I instruct gnumake to only add the `-Wno-unused-private-field` for just one source file's compilation?  I've got `-Wall` coming in via CXXFLAGS variable, how can I add another value to that variable but only for the one file's compilation?  I want to limit it to just one platform (Mac) too:

```
ifeq "$(BUILD_HOST_ARCH_NAME)" "darwin"
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-private-field
endif
```

But how do I also limit it to just one file, `foo.cpp`?

Comment: Interestingly I noticed you asked a similar question here in 2010 which suggests you knew the answer back then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726019/how-to-strip-out-a-d-for-just-one-file-in-a-gnu-makefile?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [target-specific variable value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html). Together with the platform check, it would look like this:

```
ifeq "$(BUILD_HOST_ARCH_NAME)" "darwin"
foo.o: CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-private-field
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Clang, you can control it with `#pragma` in the source code:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-private-field"

class A {
private:
    int unused;
};
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

class B {
private:
    // This still produces a warning
    int unused;
};
```

Comment: Will #ifdef's need to go around the Pragmas for the non-clang builds such as gcc or will they just ignore since not clang compilers?

Comment: @WilliamKF perhaps yes, to avoid unknown pragma/unknown option warnings

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer that comes to mind is this.

I'm not sure what where your `$(BUILD_HOST_ARCH_NAME)` comes from.  If you don't have it already, the first line is evaluating it, assuming only that there is a working `uname` command in your shell.  This is enough to distinguish Darwin from Linux, but probably not good enough for Windows.

```
BUILD_HOST_ARCH_NAME = $(shell uname -s)

CXXEXTRAFLAGS =
ifeq "$(BUILD_HOST_ARCH_NAME)" "Darwin"
CXXEXTRAFLAGS += -Wno-unused-private-field
endif

foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXEXTRAFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Then, on a Mac:

```
$ make -n foo.o
c++   -Wno-unused-private-field foo.cpp -o foo.o
$ make -n bar.o
c++  bar.cpp -o bar.o
```

Answer (score 0):

If C++17 is enabled and you need to apply that to a strict number of files, you could just use [[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused)

```
#include <cassert>
 
[[maybe_unused]] void f([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1,
                        [[maybe_unused]] bool thing2)
{
   [[maybe_unused]] bool b = thing1 && thing2;
   assert(b); // in release mode, assert is compiled out, and b is unused
              // no warning because it is declared [[maybe_unused]]
} // parameters thing1 and thing2 are not used, no warning
 
int main() {;}
```